# Как использовать основной Spring Context для асинхронного метода?

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring, асинхронность, context

Имеется приложение на `Spring Boot`-стеке. В приложении есть *асинхронный* метод, который на фоне должен выполнять действия с авторизованным пользователем, но так как асинхронный метод использует другой контекст, то авторизованного пользователя он не видит. Каким образом можно передать свой
основной context в асинхронный поток?

Асинхронность реализована через *@EnableAsync* и @Async.

SpringAsyncConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig {

    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет о доступе к `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()`, то можно использовать `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor`

```
@Bean 
public DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor delegate) { 
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(delegate); 
}
```

Тогда контекст будет содержать данные аутентикации внутри методов с аннотацией `@Async`:

```
@Async
public void asyncCall() {
    log.info("Inside the @Async logic: "
      + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
}
```

Более подробно [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-async-principal-propagation)